# Intermittently getting an error message when trying to generate a pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, url

The error message looks like "Could not render the url. Could not get image from url.Navigation timeout.."

The stack trace that i am getting is put below.

> 2016-01-04 12:01:04,684 [57] ERROR
>   ErrorId='0ece54f2-8232-4c1e-9854-c81f6a8ffa57',
>   ExceptionMessage='Exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.',
>   ExceptionStacktrace='   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)'.
>   Winnovative.WnvHtmlConvert.HtmlConvertException: Could not render the
>   url. Could not get image from url.Navigation timeout..    at
>   Winnovative.WnvHtmlConvert.ImgConverter.GetMetafileFromUrl(String url,
>   xi& htmlParseInfo)    at
>   Winnovative.WnvHtmlConvert.PdfConverter.ConvertAndGetPdfDocument(String
>   url, String htmlString, String baseUrl, String internalLinksDocUrl,
>   Boolean fromUrl)    at
>   Winnovative.WnvHtmlConvert.PdfConverter.ConvertAndSaveToStream(Stream
>   outStream, String url, String htmlString, String baseUrl, String
>   internalLinksDocUrl, Boolean fromUrl)    at
>   Winnovative.WnvHtmlConvert.PdfConverter.GetPdfBytes(String url, String
>   htmlString, String baseUrl, String internalLinksDocUrl, Boolean
>   fromUrl)    at
>   Winnovative.WnvHtmlConvert.PdfConverter.GetPdfBytesFromUrl(String url)
>   at Metrica.results.btnExportCertificates_Click(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in
>   e:\Build\Work\593ad3cfd51af9bc\Metrica\results.aspx.cs:line 612    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

```
PdfConverter pdfConverter = new PdfConverter();
        pdfConverter.LicenseKey = "///some key";
        pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfPageSize = PdfPageSize.A4;
        pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfPageOrientation = PDFPageOrientation.Portrait;
        pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfCompressionLevel = PdfCompressionLevel.Normal;
        pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.GenerateSelectablePdf = true;
        pdfConverter.ScriptsEnabled = true;
        pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.ShowFooter = false;
        pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.ShowHeader = false;
        pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.TopMargin = 0;
        pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.BottomMargin = 0;
        pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.LeftMargin = 0;
        pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.RightMargin = 0;
        string title = "Certificates";
        string url = Common.Utilities.General.GetBaseUrl() + ApplicationManager.ApplicationPath + "/generatetrf.aspx?instance=" + Server.UrlEncode(txtInstances.Text);
        byte[] downloadBytes = pdfConverter.GetPdfBytesFromUrl(url);
```

Comment: and what does your code look like?

Comment: Could it not go into the question?

Comment: added to question. thank you :)

Comment: sounds like a timeout `Could not get image from url.Navigation timeout`

Comment: Final question, what is the library you are using (it would be good to add as a tag to get direct support)

Comment: Winnovative.WnvHtmlConvert

Comment: Any idea what could be the problem is ?